# How to connect database from custom view [Android]

Tags: android, sqlite, android-custom-view

I have this database connector class with a constructor as follows

```
public class DBConnectionTableTVShow {

     public DBConnectionTableTVShow(Context ctx){
       this.context = ctx;
       dbh = new DBHelper(context);
     }
}
```

I can create object from an Activity like following

```
public class Select_episode extends Activity {

    DBConnectionTableTVShow dbcon = new DBConnectionTableTVShow(this);
}
```

Now I want to create object, like i did in above in the custom view adapter class

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{ 

}
```

How to do this?

I tried

```
DBConnectionTableTVShow dbcon = new DBConnectionTableTVShow(this);
```

this in `CustomListViewAdapter` class and it doesn't work

Complete code of Select_episode : http://pastebin.com/R1mSRrqj

Complete code of CustomListViewAdapter : http://pastebin.com/U8Zqw924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CustomListViewAdapter` is an inner class of `Select_episode` then you can use

```
DBConnectionTableTVShow dbcon = new DBConnectionTableTVShow(Select_episode.this);
```

or you can create a constructor with a Context param and instantiate your database helper using the pass in context (when you pass this it is equivalent to passing a Context so instead of Activity you should make your param Context since you only need context)

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<ListViewItem> items;
DBConnectionTableTVShow dbcon;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items) {  
    super();

    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.dbcon = new DBConnectionTableTVShow(context);
}
```

Comment: Use the first one getting the folloing error: No enclosing instance of the type Select_episode is accessible in scope

Comment: Your CustomListViewAdapter is not an inner class so you cannot use Select_episode.this so use the new DBConnectionTableTVShow(context) as you already has a constructor with Context param. I do not understand "my question last tow line" above.

Comment: I added complete code of those two class and the link are given there.  Complete code of Select_episode : http://pastebin.com/R1mSRrqj

Complete code of CustomListViewAdapter : http://pastebin.com/U8Zqw924

Comment: I saw the codes and what is your problem. If you want to instantiate a DBConnectionTableTVShow then make dbcon a class member and instantiate that in the constructor dbcon = new DBConnectionTableTVShow(context);

Comment: i could not understand u clearly. sorry about that. i am new to andorid. anyway i tried this {private  Context context;
 DBConnectionTableTVShow dbcon = new DBConnectionTableTVShow(context);   } and it give me error when i use  dbcon.open();

Comment: You have to make dbcon a class member as in my edited answer above.